How to place two Javascript functions inside one script source file?
I am absolutely new to Javascript. And I am making a web project that changes the styles of two div elements using select/option values.  However, it will not work when I attempt to put the codes together.
This is the code:
<html>
<head>

<style>
div{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid Black;
  margin: 10px; padding:6px;}

select{
  width:150px;
  height:30px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Box1" id="Box1"> This is the First Box. </div>
<div class="Box2" id="Box2"> This is the Second Box. </div>

<br><br>

<h4>First Box Style</h4>
<select name="font" id="1stfont">
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>

<select name="foreground" id="1stforeground">
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="White">White</option>
<option value="Brown">Brown</option>
</select>

<select name="background" id="1stbackground">
<option value="White">White</option>
<option value="Tan">Tan</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option>
</select>

<select name="bgImage" id="1stbgImage">
<option value="url('https://sadhost.neocities.org/images/tiles/leavesbg.gif')">Pattern #1</option>
<option value="url('https://sadhost.neocities.org/images/tiles/tumblr_inline_mlkxsmQayT1r53miq540.gif')">Pattern #2</option>
<option value="url('https://sadhost.neocities.org/images/tiles/gifbground-804-0005.gif')">Pattern #3</option>
</select> 

<br><br>

<h4>Second Box Style</h4>
<select name="font" id="2ndfont">
<option value="Arial">Arial</option>
<option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>

<select name="foreground" id="2ndforeground">
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="White">White</option>
<option value="Brown">Brown</option>
</select>

<select name="background" id="2ndbackground">
<option value="White">White</option>
<option value="Tan">Tan</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option>
</select>

<select name="bgImage" id="2ndbgImage">
<option value="url('https://sadhost.neocities.org/images/tiles/leavesbg.gif')">Pattern #1</option>
<option value="url('https://sadhost.neocities.org/images/tiles/tumblr_inline_mlkxsmQayT1r53miq540.gif')">Pattern #2</option>
<option value="url('https://sadhost.neocities.org/images/tiles/gifbground-804-0005.gif')">Pattern #3</option>
</select> 

<script>
var change = document.getElementById('Box1');

document.getElementById('1stforeground').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.color = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('1stfont').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.fontFamily = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('1stbackground').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('1stbgImage').addEventListener('change', function(){
 change.style.backgroundImage = this.value;
});

var change = document.getElementById('Box2');

document.getElementById('2ndforeground').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.color = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('2ndfont').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.fontFamily = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('2ndbackground').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('2ndbgImage').addEventListener('change', function(){
 change.style.backgroundImage = this.value;
});

</script>
</body>
</html>

I already tried the following and I probably did all of them wrong:

Link to two source files.
Combine them into one script (whether with function() or combining variables)
Place them as separate scripts inside an html document.

EDIT: It only changes the second box.
EDIT: I am using it to make a web button maker on my secondary domain webhost website.

I got the JS code from here: https://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/bNVxyP

see how you have two var change = ... use a different variable name for the two boxes, because the event handlers use the current (last) value of change not the value you were thinking of like in a card trick.

I tried it. It didn't work for me. I am using a text editor. I think the problem is I am not connecting the functions right.  And I do not where to learn to do this. The first half of the script is for Box1 and second half is for Box2. And there is no declaration to indicate the change in function. But, how??

See my answer. I just fixed a typo :-)

I tried it doesn't look like it. It didn't work for me we can't see what you did. I think the problem is ... exactly what I said it is

of course, the other options would be 1: to use an IIFE for each "copy" of the code, 2: to use a separate module script for each copy of the code, and 3: a function which you call with the various id's you need for each

Yes! It worked! I was confused with the code at first. Sorry! Thank you.

repetitive code makes debugging harder -  your whole js could be less than 10 lines long with good use of data attributes - https://jsfiddle.net/wv63Lmbu/

First of all, this way of assigning handlers isn't really ideal. Imagine you had to deal with a dynamic number of selectors, for example.
In any case, seeing as that is outside the scope of the question, you'll solve your issue by not reusing change as a variable name between the two elements.
Also, you can't repeat var change = ... multiple times in the same function. The first time you declare the variable, you can use: var change = ... and, if you want to modify the value assigned to that variable later on in your function, you would simply use: change = ..., without repeating var.
For your case in particular, you'll want to use two different variables until you learn to dynamically assign event listeners, etc. to your different elements programmatically.
Your code should look as follows:
<script>
var change = document.getElementById('Box1');

document.getElementById('1stforeground').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.color = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('1stfont').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.fontFamily = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('1stbackground').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
});

var change2 = document.getElementById('Box2');

document.getElementById('2ndforeground').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change2.style.color = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('2ndfont').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change2.style.fontFamily = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('2ndbackground').addEventListener('change', function(){
  change2.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
});

</script>

The reason your original code was only changing the second box, was that you were actually reassigning the value for the change variable. That means, that the last time your performed a: change = document.getElementById('blah'); would override every other time you assigned a value to it.

Yes! It worked! Thank you.
